# How or can I run SOLR delta query with SOLRNET

Tags: solr

How or can I run SOLR delta query with SOLRNET ?  Can I call the /dataimport with any parameters in SOLR admin ?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=78

Answer (score 0):

[Commands](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Commands)

You can perform delta import with `http://<host>:<port>/solr/dataimport?command=delta-import`
Also, the DIH calls are asynchronous, as far as I remember, so you would receive an immediate response and have to keep polling to check the status.

Comment: @Greens, Please share if you are able to make it work with SolrNet ? . If yes, please share the code snippet..